# System service is not available to activities before onCreate()

Tags: android, xml, button, service

I'm new to android development and I'm here to seek for help.

I've coded a wallet program and when i press the debit button , it stopped working and crashes.

Is it because of the `final Context context` declaration ?

My logcat error starts from here

```
: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

Main class activity :

```
private double total; //total amount
    EditText et;
    private double cinput; //credit input
    private double dinput; //debit input
    Button CreditButton;
    Button DebitButton;
    final Context context = this;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //loadAmt();
    cinput = 0;
    dinput = 0;
    CreditButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CreditButton);
    DebitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DebitButton);
    CreditButton.setOnClickListener(new ButtonActionListener());
    DebitButton.setOnClickListener(new ButtonActionListener());
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.AmountText);
    et.setText(String.valueOf(total));
}

public void loadAmt() {

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class ButtonActionListener extends MainActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.DebitButton) {
            try {
                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // get user input and set it to result
                                        // edit text
                                        String inputString = userInput.getText().toString();
                                        dinput = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
                                        total = total + dinput;
                                        et.setText(String.valueOf(total));


                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only Numbers Are Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.CreditButton) {
            try {
                // get prompts.xml view
                LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.prompts, null);

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        context);

                // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
                alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

                final EditText userInput = (EditText) promptsView
                        .findViewById(R.id.editTextDialogUserInput);

                // set dialog message
                alertDialogBuilder
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton("OK",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        // get user input and set it to result
                                        // edit text
                                        String inputString = userInput.getText().toString();
                                        cinput = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
                                        total = total - cinput;
                                        et.setText(String.valueOf(total));

                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        dialog.cancel();
                                    }
                                });

                // create alert dialog
                AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

                // show it
                alertDialog.show();
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Only Numbers Are Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        //save(total);


    public void save(double tamt) {

        SharedPreferences spamount = getSharedPreferences("TotalAmount", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spamount.edit();
        editor.putString("LastAmount", String.valueOf(tamt));
        editor.apply();

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes its because **it because of the `context` initialization before `onCreate`**

Comment: I tried to remove the final declaration and do it in onCreate but it shows "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference"

Comment: `Your error is not related to your question. so first you decide what is your error?`

Comment: My actual error is the context problem, i tried to declare it outside onCreate and inside onCreate , both error , i'm sorry for the title

Comment: Oh yes. I forgot to changed it back after i test something. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will only get the context of your activity in the Activity lifecycle methods. So you should initialize it inside the onCreate method.

```
private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;
}
```

Comment: But if i declare it inside it shows that I'm pointing to null , it returns me a nullpointerexception

Comment: Did you placed it as it is in the answer? i.e after the `setContentView()`

Comment: Owh , i think i missed the private key word, Thanks !